# Checking an asp.NET server for issues via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Does anyone know how I would check a remote server for any of the following asp.NET security issues from .NET C#? Are these settings viewable via a special address or page on the server? Possibly in a HTTP Header?

Issues:
ASP.NET Debugging Enabled
ASP.NET Trace Enabled
ViewState is not Signed
ViewState is not Encrypted

Comment: You've read [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2009/10/24/five-common-mistakes-in-the-web-config-file.aspx)?

Comment: not specific to that, but you might want to check out https://asafaweb.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ANSA - [Asp.Net Security Analyzer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ANSA) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733716/finding-security-holes-tools-for-asp-net).

Comment: Thanks for this response however, I was curious how to check for these problems using C# opposed to a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Not reliable doing it yourself unless there's a specific threat you're monitoring.